# Is it possible to use the system console to display output?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, windows-console

I'd like to have IntelliJ display output via the standard output streams in the **native system console** (in this case, the Windows console) rather than in the integrated IDE tab. Is there any way I can do this without having to manually run my app via the `java` command. The reason for this is so I can use [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi).

Comment: And IntelliJ console does not display the colors?

Comment: @Vanna That's exactly how I'd like to display the output, however I don't want to have to manually run my app through the native console.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132822#comment=27-854393

Comment: You can run your app in `cmd.exe` from IntelliJ IDEA like described in [this forum thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000244884-Can-t-find-the-Command-Line-Tool-to-install-it).

Comment: @Meo That actually just answered my question, you should make an answer and I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @PavanChohan you can answer it yourself and mark your own answer as accepted.